# How to use a .js file as a background?

Tags: javascript, background

I have a .js file with a simple animation that I'd like to use as a website's background. I'm able to put it onto the page and all that- but the text appears below the animation instead of over it. I've tried looking up solutions but all I've been able to find is instructions for making setting a .png/.jpg as the  background. I'm very new to programming, so I haven't the slightest idea how I'd do this. Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Here's the code I'm trying to use!

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Scrolling Page</title> 
</head> 
<body style="background-color: black;"> 
   <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas> 
<h1>Text</h1>
<p>text</p>
</body>
</html>

<script src="mainscript.js"></script>
```

mainscript.js is:

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1'); 
var ctx = can.getContext('2d'); 
can.width = 9200; 
can.height = 630; 
var img = new Image(); 
img.src = "tempimage.png";
window.onload = function() { 
    var imgWidth = 0; 
    var scrollSpeed = 10; 
    function loop() 
    { 
        ctx.drawImage(img, imgWidth, 0); 
        ctx.drawImage(img, imgWidth - can.width, 0); 
        imgWidth -= scrollSpeed; 
        if (-imgWidth == can.width) 
            imgWidth = 0; 
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop); 
    } 
    loop();
```

Comment: Please always include the code you are referring to in your question. Without that, it's unlikely we can help.

Comment: @scott-marcus My bad, sorry! Edited the post with the code.

Comment: You say that your canvas animation works?

Comment: Yes, the animation works.

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because we're not talking about using just a picture as a background and instead an HTML `canvas` element that is being animated, you'll need to use CSS to layer the `canvas` element that you want to use as a background behind the rest of the page content. To do that, you can position the background element with [`position:absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and then place it behind everything else with [`z-index:-1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <title>Scrolling Page</title> 
  <style>
    #canvas1 {
      position:absolute;    /* Take the element out of the normal document flow */
      z-index:-1;           /* Place the element behind normal content */
      top:0;                /* Start at top of viewport */
      left:0;               /* Start at left edge of viewport */  
    }
  </style>
</head> 
<body> 
  <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas> 
  <h1>Text</h1>
  <p>text</p>

  <script>
    var can = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    can.width = 9200; 
    can.height = 630; 
    var img = new Image(); 
    img.src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/02/19/19/45/thumbs-up-4007573__340.png";
    window.onload = function() { 
      var imgWidth = 0; 
      var scrollSpeed = 10; 
      function loop() { 
        ctx.drawImage(img, imgWidth, 0); 
        ctx.drawImage(img, imgWidth - can.width, 0); 
        imgWidth -= scrollSpeed; 
        if (-imgWidth == can.width) {
            imgWidth = 0; 
        }
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop); 
      } 
      loop();
    }  
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```